# Starting a process in the Dockerfile

Tags: docker, dockerfile

My problem is the following: I need to start a container with the dnsmasq service running (but that could be any service). The hard point is that I created a user in my image, so when I create a container out of it, it starts with my custom user (no root).

Therefore, how can I start a service that requires root privileges (sudo service dnsmasq start), with a non-root user ?

Possible solutions:

- be able to start a container with the service already running. From What I understand, this is not possible to start a service in a Dockerfile, because it doesn't retain the state, only the FS
- start the container as root, start the service, then switch back to the user. That could work, but potentially a security issue
- let my custom user have the right to start the service by himself. How to do that ?
- don't use a custom user (probably the easiest way, but hey ? Where's the fun in that ? :))

Any other solution ?

Comment: How about this answer: http://askubuntu.com/a/90727
. You can then set it so the user doesn't need to enter their password using `NOPASSWD`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to Rickkwa comment, I was able to fix the problem:

In the Dockerfile (as root):

```
# Install and configure Dnsmasq
RUN apt-get update && apt-get install -y dnsmasq
# Need to add a new line
RUN echo '' >> /etc/dnsmasq.conf
# See https://github.com/nicolasff/docker-cassandra/issues/8
RUN echo 'user=root' >> /etc/dnsmasq.conf
# Add the needed route
RUN echo 'address=/my-domain.com/<my_ip>' >> /etc/dnsmasq.conf

# Allow my user's group to start the service
RUN echo ''%${group}' ALL=NOPASSWD:/usr/sbin/service dnsmasq *' >> /etc/sudoers

# Switch to the right user, that belongs to the group ${group}
USER ${user}
```

Then, when your container starts (in the entrypoint, for instance), add the following line:

```
sudo service dnsmasq start
```

Remember the `NOPASSWD` in the `/etc/sudoers` files ? This prevents the system asking for the user's password when we launch the service.

Answer (score -1):

What about using entrypoint, that run shell script to do what you want

Comment: That won't work because the user I start the container with has not the required rights.

Comment: you can use something like this

CMD sudo ["/usr/startup.sh"]

or you can change user inside dockerfile using this

User [your_user]